# How to join rdd rows based on common value in another column RDD pyspark

Tags: pyspark, mapreduce, rdd

Textfile Dataset I have :

```
Benz,25
BMW,27
BMW,25
Land Rover,22
Audi,25
Benz,25
```

The result I want is :

```
[((Benz,BMW),2),((Benz,Audi),1),((BMW,Audi),1)]
```

it basically pairs the cars with common values and gets the occurrence together.

My code so far is :

```
cars= sc.textFile('cars.txt')
carpair= cars.flatMap(lambda x: float(x.split(',')))
carpair.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1])).groupByKey().collect()
```

As I'm a beginner I'm not able to figure it out.

Getting the occurrence is secondary i cant even map the values together.

Answer (score 0):

In pyspark, it'd look like this:

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField('car_model', StringType(), True),
    StructField('value', IntegerType(), True)
])
df = (
    spark
    .read
    .schema(schema)
    .option('header', False)
    .csv('./cars.txt')
)

(
    df.alias('left')
    .join(df.alias('right'), ['value'], 'left')
    .select('value', f.col('left.car_model').alias('left_car_model'), f.col('right.car_model').alias('right_car_model'))
    .where(f.col('left_car_model') != f.col('right_car_model'))
    .groupBy('left_car_model', 'right_car_model')
    .agg(f.count('*').alias('count'))
    .show()
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but how to do it with RDD only?

Comment: The RDDs are slower than both the Dataframes and the Datasets to perform simple functions. Check out this link for comparing RDDs, Dataframes, and Datasets: https://www.projectpro.io/recipes/what-is-difference-between-rdds-datasets-and-dataframes-apache-spark